I want to add my own new menu to Chromium, but I'm having a problem
I am new to Chromium development.
Add a new parent menu to the top right menu of Chromium, create a submenu called Help and Settings, for example, and click the internal URL (ex: test://settings or test://help custom) when you click on each submenu. If one scheme is difficult, I would like to open the HTML I wrote through chrome://test-settings or chrome://help. But I've been trying for two weeks and I keep getting stuck.
With the code I've modified so far, I can see the submenu in the menu and click on it, but it doesn't show up in the console:
[2558072:2558072:0710/121539.983950:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(414)] Debug LHS: URL spec is securitynet://help/
[2558072:2558072:0710/121539.983991:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(415)] Debug LHS: URL scheme is securitynet
[2558072:2558072:0710/121539.984023:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(416)] Debug LHS: URL host is help
[2558072:2558072:0710/121539.984054:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(417)] Debug LHS: URL host_piece is help
[2558072:2558072:0710/121539.984083:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(418)] Debug LHS: URL path is /
[2558072:2558072:0710/121539.984116:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(422)] Processing LHS1 SecurityNet VPN URL: securitynet://help/
[2558072:2558072:0710/121539.984147:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(423)] Processing URL host is help
[2558072:2558072:0710/121539.984181:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(425)] Creating SecurityNetVpnHelpUI
[2558072:2558072:0710/121539.984216:INFO:securitynet_vpn_ui.cc(16)] lhs SecurityNetVpnHelpUI called
[2558072:2558072:0710/121539.984294:INFO:securitynet_vpn_ui.cc(21)] AddResourcePath securityNetVpnHelpUI called
[2558072:2558072:0710/121539.984338:INFO:securitynet_vpn_ui.cc(23)] SetDefaultResource securityNetVpnHelpUI called
[2558072:2558072:0710/121539.984369:INFO:securitynet_vpn_ui.cc(25)] Current WebUI Bindings: 3
[2558072:2558072:0710/121540.000615:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(414)] Debug LHS: URL spec is securitynet://help/
[2558072:2558072:0710/121540.000696:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(415)] Debug LHS: URL scheme is securitynet
[2558072:2558072:0710/121540.000735:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(416)] Debug LHS: URL host is help
[2558072:2558072:0710/121540.000767:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(417)] Debug LHS: URL host_piece is help
[2558072:2558072:0710/121540.000798:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(418)] Debug LHS: URL path is /
[2558072:2558072:0710/121540.000832:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(422)] Processing LHS1 SecurityNet VPN URL: securitynet://help/
[2558072:2558072:0710/121540.000863:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(423)] Processing URL host is help
[2558072:2558072:0710/121540.000910:INFO:chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc(425)] Creating SecurityNetVpnHelpUI
[2558072:2558072:0710/121540.001025:FATAL:render_frame_host_impl.cc(6596)] Check failed: false. Calling AllowBindings for a process not locked to WebUI:{ securitynet://help/ }

It logs and just quits.
I am attaching code that I modified or added arbitrarily. Please advise if you can.
generated_resources.grd
  <message name="IDS_SECURITYNET_VPN_MENU" desc="The label of the SecuritynetVPN menu item">
      SecuritynetVPN
    </message>
    <message name="IDS_SECURITYNET_VPN_HELP" desc="The label of the SecuritynetVPN Help submenu item">
      SecuritynetVPN Help
    </message>
    <message name="IDS_SECURITYNET_VPN_SETTINGS" desc="The label of the SecuritynetVPN Settings submenu item">
      SecuritynetVPN Settings
    </message>
  </messages>
  <includes>
    <include name="IDR_SECURITYNET_VPN_HELP_HTML" file="../browser/resources/securitynet/help.html" type="BINDATA" />
    <include name="IDR_SECURITYNET_VPN_SETTINGS_HTML" file="../browser/resources/securitynet/settings.html" type="BINDATA" />
  </includes>

chrome_web_ui_controller_factory.cc
//securitynet
template <>
WebUIController* NewWebUI<SecurityNetVpnHelpUI>(WebUI* web_ui, const GURL& url) {
  return new SecurityNetVpnHelpUI(web_ui);
}

template <>
WebUIController* NewWebUI<SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI>(WebUI* web_ui, const GURL& url) {
  return new SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI(web_ui);
}

WebUIFactoryFunction GetWebUIFactoryFunction(WebUI* web_ui,
                                             Profile* profile,
                                             const GURL& url) {

  LOG(INFO) << "Debug LHS: URL spec is " << url.spec();
  LOG(INFO) << "Debug LHS: URL scheme is " << url.scheme();
  LOG(INFO) << "Debug LHS: URL host is " << url.host();
  LOG(INFO) << "Debug LHS: URL host_piece is " << url.host_piece();
  LOG(INFO) << "Debug LHS: URL path is " << url.path();

//securitynet
if (url.SchemeIs(chrome::kSecuritynetVPNScheme)) {
  LOG(INFO) << "Processing LHS1 SecurityNet VPN URL: " << url.spec();
  LOG(INFO) << "Processing URL host is " << url.host();
  if (url.host() == "help") {
    LOG(INFO) << "Creating SecurityNetVpnHelpUI";
    return &NewWebUI<SecurityNetVpnHelpUI>;
  } else if (url.host() == "settings") {
    LOG(INFO) << "Creating SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI";
    return &NewWebUI<SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI>;
  }
  LOG(WARNING) << "Unknown SecurityNet VPN URL: " << url.spec();
}

app_menu_model.cc
void AppMenuModel::Build() {
  // Build (and, by extension, Init) should only be called once.
  DCHECK_EQ(0u, GetItemCount());

  // securitynet:SecuritynetVPN 메뉴 추가
  auto securitynet_vpn_sub_menu = std::make_unique<ui::SimpleMenuModel>(this);
  securitynet_vpn_sub_menu->AddItemWithStringId(IDC_SECURITYNET_VPN_HELP, IDS_SECURITYNET_VPN_HELP);
  securitynet_vpn_sub_menu->AddItemWithStringId(IDC_SECURITYNET_VPN_SETTINGS, IDS_SECURITYNET_VPN_SETTINGS);

  AddSubMenuWithStringIdAndVectorIcon(this, IDC_SECURITYNET_VPN_MENU, IDS_SECURITYNET_VPN_MENU, securitynet_vpn_sub_menu.get(), kNewWindowIcon);

  sub_menus_.push_back(std::move(securitynet_vpn_sub_menu));

void AppMenuModel::ExecuteCommand(int command_id, int event_flags) {

  switch (command_id) {
    // ... (기존 case 문들)
    case IDC_SECURITYNET_VPN_HELP:
      chrome::OpenSecuritynetVPNHelp(browser_);
      break;
    case IDC_SECURITYNET_VPN_SETTINGS:
      chrome::OpenSecuritynetVPNSettings(browser_);
      break;
    default:
      break;
    // ... (기존 default case)
  }

chrome_content_client.cc
void ChromeContentClient::AddAdditionalSchemes(Schemes* schemes) {
  for (auto* standard_scheme : kChromeStandardURLSchemes)
    schemes->standard_schemes.push_back(standard_scheme);
  // SecurityNet VPN 스키마 추가
  
  schemes->standard_schemes.push_back(chrome::kSecuritynetVPNScheme);
  schemes->secure_schemes.push_back(chrome::kSecuritynetVPNScheme);
  schemes->cors_enabled_schemes.push_back(chrome::kSecuritynetVPNScheme);
  schemes->csp_bypassing_schemes.push_back(chrome::kSecuritynetVPNScheme);
  schemes->local_schemes.push_back(chrome::kSecuritynetVPNScheme);
  schemes->no_access_schemes.push_back(chrome::kSecuritynetVPNScheme);
  schemes->service_worker_schemes.push_back(chrome::kSecuritynetVPNScheme);
  LOG(INFO) << "SecurityNet VPN scheme added to additional schemes";

securitynet_vpn_ui.cc
#include "chrome/browser/ui/webui/securitynet_vpn_ui.h"

#include "content/public/browser/web_contents.h"
#include "content/public/browser/web_ui.h"
#include "content/public/browser/web_ui_data_source.h"
#include "chrome/common/url_constants.h"
#include "chrome/grit/generated_resources.h"
#include "base/logging.h"
#include "content/public/browser/render_frame_host.h"
#include "content/public/common/bindings_policy.h"

SecurityNetVpnHelpUI::SecurityNetVpnHelpUI(content::WebUI* web_ui)
    : TopChromeWebUIController(web_ui, /*enable_chrome_send=*/true) {
    LOG(INFO) << "lhs SecurityNetVpnHelpUI called";

    web_ui->SetBindings(content::BINDINGS_POLICY_WEB_UI);
    LOG(INFO) << "Current WebUI Bindings: " << web_ui->GetBindings();

    content::WebUIDataSource* source = content::WebUIDataSource::CreateAndAdd(
        web_ui->GetWebContents()->GetBrowserContext(),
        chrome::kSecuritynetVPNScheme);
    source->AddResourcePath("help.html", IDR_SECURITYNET_VPN_HELP_HTML);
    LOG(INFO) << "AddResourcePath securityNetVpnHelpUI called";
    source->SetDefaultResource(IDR_SECURITYNET_VPN_HELP_HTML);
    LOG(INFO) << "SetDefaultResource securityNetVpnHelpUI called";

    content::RenderFrameHost* frame_host = web_ui->GetWebContents()->GetPrimaryMainFrame();
    frame_host->AllowBindings(content::BINDINGS_POLICY_WEB_UI);
    LOG(INFO) << "Frame Host Bindings After: " << frame_host->GetEnabledBindings();
}

SecurityNetVpnHelpUI::~SecurityNetVpnHelpUI() = default;

SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI::SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI(content::WebUI* web_ui)
    : TopChromeWebUIController(web_ui, /*enable_chrome_send=*/true) {
    LOG(INFO) << "lhs SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI called";

    web_ui->SetBindings(content::BINDINGS_POLICY_WEB_UI);
    LOG(INFO) << "Current WebUI Bindings: " << web_ui->GetBindings();

    content::WebUIDataSource* source = content::WebUIDataSource::CreateAndAdd(
        web_ui->GetWebContents()->GetBrowserContext(),
        chrome::kSecuritynetVPNScheme);
    source->AddResourcePath("settings.html", IDR_SECURITYNET_VPN_SETTINGS_HTML);
    LOG(INFO) << "AddResourcePath SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI called";
    source->SetDefaultResource(IDR_SECURITYNET_VPN_SETTINGS_HTML);
    LOG(INFO) << "SetDefaultResource SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI called";

    content::RenderFrameHost* frame_host = web_ui->GetWebContents()->GetPrimaryMainFrame();
    frame_host->AllowBindings(content::BINDINGS_POLICY_WEB_UI);
    LOG(INFO) << "Frame Host Bindings After: " << frame_host->GetEnabledBindings();
}

SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI::~SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI() = default;

securitynet_vpn_ui.h
#ifndef CHROME_BROWSER_UI_WEBUI_SECURITYNET_VPN_SECURITYNET_VPN_UI_H_
#define CHROME_BROWSER_UI_WEBUI_SECURITYNET_VPN_SECURITYNET_VPN_UI_H_

#include "chrome/browser/ui/webui/top_chrome/top_chrome_web_ui_controller.h"

class SecurityNetVpnHelpUI : public TopChromeWebUIController {
 public:
  explicit SecurityNetVpnHelpUI(content::WebUI* web_ui);
  ~SecurityNetVpnHelpUI() override;

  SecurityNetVpnHelpUI(const SecurityNetVpnHelpUI&) = delete;
  SecurityNetVpnHelpUI& operator=(const SecurityNetVpnHelpUI&) = delete;
};

class SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI : public TopChromeWebUIController {
 public:
  explicit SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI(content::WebUI* web_ui);
  ~SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI() override;

  SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI(const SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI&) = delete;
  SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI& operator=(const SecurityNetVpnSettingsUI&) = delete;
};

#endif  // CHROME_BROWSER_UI_WEBUI_SECURITYNET_VPN_SECURITYNET_VPN_UI_H_

chrome/common/webui_url_constants.cc

namespace chrome {

const char kSecuritynetVPNScheme[] = "securitynet";
const char kSecuritynetVPNHelpHost[] = "help";
const char kSecuritynetVPNSettingsHost[] = "settings";

I am attaching it because there is missing code.
browser_commands.cc
//securitynet
void OpenSecuritynetVPNHelp(Browser* browser) {
 LOG(INFO) << "OpenSecuritynetVPNHelp called";
 GURL help_url(chrome::kChromeUISecurityNetHelpURL);
 LOG(INFO) << "Help URL: " << help_url.spec() << ", Host: " << help_url.host();

 content::OpenURLParams params(
 help_url,
 content::Referrer(),
 WindowOpenDisposition::SINGLETON_TAB;
 ui::PAGE_TRANSITION_AUTO_TOPLEVEL,
 false);

 browser->OpenURL(params, base::DoNothing());
}

void OpenSecuritynetVPNSettings(Browser* browser) {
 LOG(INFO) << "OpenSecuritynetVPNSettings called";
 GURL settings_url(chrome::kChromeUISecurityNetSettingsURL);
 LOG(INFO) << "Settings URL: " << settings_url.spec() << ", Host: " << settings_url.host();

 content::OpenURLParams params(
 settings_url,
 content::Referrer(),
 WindowOpenDisposition::SINGLETON_TAB;
 ui::PAGE_TRANSITION_AUTO_TOPLEVEL,
 false);

 browser->OpenURL(params, base::DoNothing());
}

When you click on the submenu of the menu, it moves to securitynet://help in the address bar and loads help.html.

You might want to ask this question on the official Chromium dev group: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-dev
